# Strange issue in equals comparison

Tags: java, nullpointerexception, equals

I am having a strange issue with the followin syntax:

The following code block doesn't throw null pointer exception

```
Map<String, String> requestHeaderMap = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap();

if(!"partial/ajax".equals(requestHeaderMap.get("faces-request")))    
{
    System.out.println("This works");
}
```

But this one throws null pointer exception:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap().get("faces-request").equals("partial/ajax")
```

I just couldn't figure out whats wrong here. I don't see any difference between two call except for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two do things in different orders. It's like the difference between `x.equals(y)` and `y.equals(x)`. If `y` is null, only the second one of those will throw an NPE. In your case, `requestHeaderMap.get("faces-request")` is null.

This doesn't throw the exception because *.equals(null) is perfectly fine:

```
"partial/ajax".equals(requestHeaderMap.get("faces-request")
```

On the other hand, this is trying to dereference null:

```
getRequestHeaderMap().get("faces-request").equals("partial/ajax")
```

Answer (score 6):

`FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRequestHeaderMap().get("faces-request")` is null.  Your version that works does so because you have the equals reversed, the two operations boil down to:

```
null.equals(object)
```

or

```
object.equals(null)
```

the first throws a `NullPointerException`, the second evaulates to false.

Answer (score 1):

```
if(!"partial/ajax".equals(requestHeaderMap.get("faces-request")))
```

is true because this means

```
if( !("partial/ajax".equals(null)).
```

If you try

```
null.equals("partial/ajax")
```

this will raise the the exception.

Answer (score 0):

It's because `getRequestHeaderMap().get("faces-request")` can return `null` and `null.equals("partial/ajax")` throws an exceoption.

However, `"partial/ajax".equals(...)` will never throw an exception, even if it is being compared with `null`.

That, in my personal opnion, is the **only** good thing about this `Joda` construct.